# What is the best way to strip the domain from all links and references?

Tags: domain

Wordpress puts the domain name in every single image, css LINK element and any other reference. Many users have issues because of this when it comes to moving the page or accessing it from multiple domains. There are only a few situations in multisites when the behaviour is helpful because some assets are shared.

It is not possible to clear the *siteurl* option field in admin interface. What is the best way of getting rid of the domain? I read in the Wordpress source code. All these URL generating functions directly use the option *siteurl*. So the best way seems to be clearing *siteurl* in *wp_options* table, but this breaks Wordpress.

Another approach would be hooking into *site_url* action. But this has a strange behaviour restoring full URLs and is not always called.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea and not really how WP works. WP provides filters for manipulation of code settings and options - there is one for site_url - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/site_url/ - you could use it to alter how this function works, without breaking WP itself.

Comment: Why do you want this? I would not recommend doing this. It would also mean any code that uses `switch_to_blog` wouldn't work right when showing permalinks of posts on other sites in a multisite, as well as broken canonical URLs in headings